# Evaluating limits to infinity of a power

Tags: limits

I have been asked to evaluated the limits of the following:

$$\lim \limits_{n\to \infty} a^n \ for \  a ∈ R$$

All that I know is that there are different limits depending on a. I believe that it is infinite if |a| > 1, and 0 if |a| < 1 and 1 if a = 1. But I have no way of proving this or calculating a = -1. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: limit does not exist for a=-1

Comment: Hint:  If $a = -1$, then $|a| = 1$, while $(-1)^n = -1$ for $n$ odd, and $(-1)^n = 1$ for $n$ even.

Comment: Hints: look at the series $a_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^n$, what is the limit? say $a \le -1$ - does the limit of $a^n$ exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you start with a > 1. Suppose the limit is a number $r \in \mathbb{R}$.

Then (by the definition of limit) $\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^+, \exists n \in \mathbb{R}^+: |a^n - r| \leq \epsilon$. All good, apparently.

But what happens if you take the exponent $s = \log{(2\epsilon + r)}/\log{a}$? Therefore the limit cannot be a real number $r$. You can then suppose that the function is limited, in that there exists some $\hat{r} \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{R}^+: a^n < \hat{r}$. But...

For $0 \leq a < 1$ you can reason on similar terms, but remember that $\log a < 0$ in this case, so when you divide an inequality by $\log a$...

For $a = 1$...

For $a < 0$ one has to remember that on the real axis:

$a^n \equiv e^{n \log{a}}$

therefore you can only meaningfully consider $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then compare the *modulus* of $a^n$ to the case of positive $a$, and remember that if the modulus diverges...

Answer (score 0):

The limit does not exist as the terms alternate between two values infinitely never approaching one single value. If you look at the actual definition of limit, the sequence must be within some $\varepsilon$-ball for any $\varepsilon > 0$ of a number for some tail of the sequence, but this sequence just goes $$(a_n) = (-1,1,-1,\ldots)$$
so the distance from any potential limit point always changes by $2$ infinitely often, thus it cannot be within any $\varepsilon$-ball of any point when $\varepsilon < 2$.